# Export URDF from STL

Tags: ros, urdf, plugin, solidworks, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Id like to know if its possible to export a working URDF of a ground vehicle from a complete STL file. ??
Can i know How?. I do not have the individual parts of the complete robot.Just a complete stl file.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214665/export-urdf-from-stl/) by [raghu.s1211](https://answers.ros.org/users/11086/raghu.s1211/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Working? Sure.

Have it (I assume the Solidworks to URDF exporter plugni) automagically add joints and separate your STL into different parts: no.

You'll have to either find a proper model of your vehicle and use that as a base, or cut up the mesh you have now and manually add the mates/joints. After that, you can export it to a URDF.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1